# upload an image on a server Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

I am developping an iOS application with Swift 4.

I need to upload an image from my application on a server to save it later  into the database. I search for solutions for that; First I used base64Encoding, The image is transformed to String and I store  it in the database, then when i want to upload this image, I decode it with base64 Decoding,but, I get a black [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK6Ku.jpg).

So, I tried to upload the image on the server using this code :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
@IBAction func selectPicture(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let ImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    ImagePicker.delegate = self
    ImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

    self.present(ImagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    image.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
@IBAction func upload_request(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    UploadRequest()
}
func UploadRequest()
{
    let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.101.13/upload.php")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()


    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    if (image.image == nil)
    {
        return
    }

    let image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.image!)


    if(image_data == nil)
    {
        return
    }
    let body = NSMutableData()

    let fname = "test.png"
    let mimetype = "image/png"


    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"test\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("hi\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append(image_data!)
    body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)


    request.httpBody = body as Data

    let session = URLSession.shared


    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard ((data) != nil), let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        if let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        {
            print(dataString)
        }

    }) 

    task.resume()

}
func generateBoundaryString() -> String
{
    return "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
}
```

}

and the php code :

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "image.png")) {
echo "File uploaded: ".$_FILES["file"]["name"];}
```

But I get these warnings, and the image isn't uploaded on the server :

```
move_uploaded_file(image.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/upload.php
move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phprJ2M6j' to 'image.png' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/upload.php
```

How can I succeed in uploading image on the server.

Comment: You say, "the image isn't uploaded on the server".  Does that mean the file `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phprJ2M6` does not exist?

Comment: yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: Does the directory exist?  Do you have permission to write into it?

Comment: yes, the directory exists.I change the permission with chmod 777

Comment: Well, this sentence you posted strikes me as odd: Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phprJ2M6j' to 'image.png' - shouldn't that be the other way around? Unable to move 'image.png' to /YourDirectory? Check the PHP file that handles the file upload and make sure you aren't trying to save a file location into an image.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me with custom image name `

```
    func HITtheSERVER(imageData:Data) {
         let formatter = DateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"
                  let stringOfDateTimeStamp = formatter.string(from: Date())
           //        print("Date time stamp String: \(stringOfDateTimeStamp)")
            let remoteName = "IMG_\(stringOfDateTimeStamp)"+".png"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    var body = Data()
    let fname = remoteName
    let mimetype = "image/png"

    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(
        using: String.Encoding.utf8,
    allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"test\"\r\n\r\n".data(
        using: String.Encoding.utf8,
    allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    body.append("hi\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8,allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8,allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"myFile\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8,allowLossyConversion: false)!)

    body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8,allowLossyConversion: false)!)

    body.append(imageData)
    body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8,allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8,allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    request.setValue(String(body.count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

    request.httpBody = body


    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data as NSData?, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print(dataString as Any)

    }

    task.resume()



}
func generateBoundaryString() -> String
   {
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
   }`
```